Prove that $f(\| x+y \| ) = f(\| x \| ) + f(\| y \| )$ assuming that is a convex non-decreasing non-negative function and $y=kx$ ($k > 0$)
I'm trying to solve the following question:

Assume that $f : [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is convex and continuously differentiable where $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$. $X$ is a normed vector space on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\dim X \geq 2$. Show that for each $0 \neq x \in X$ and real $\alpha > 0$ there exist $y \in X$ such that $\| y \| =\alpha$ and $f(\| x+y \| )=f(\| x \| )+f(\| y \| )$

My attempt: defining $y=\frac{\alpha}{\| x \| }x$ it's obvious that $y \in X$ and $\|  y \| =\alpha$.
For the equality given the fact that $f(0)=0$ we can conclude that $f(\lambda x) \leq \lambda f(x)$ if $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$ and from that it follows that $f(\| x \| ) + f(\| y \| ) \leq f(\| x \| +\| y \| )$.
For the other direction I'm not sure what to do. Since $f'(0) =0$ and $f$ is convex then f is non-decreasing. I tried to use this fact with triangle inequality of the norm but I wasn't able to reach the inequality.

Where is this question from? Also did you mean $y= \alpha x/\Vert x\Vert$ in your attempt?

@Pranay it's an exercise given by our prof I'm not sure from wich textbook and regrading $y$ yes.

With the restriction $y = kx$, $k > 0$, the condition $\dim X \ge 2$ becomes irrelevant, and the inequality becomes $f((k+1)| x | ) = f(| x | ) + f( k | x | )$, which is wrong for a strictly convex function.

@MartinR $f((k+1)||x||) = f(||x||) + f(k||x||)$ is what I'm trying to prove. But as I explained in my question I'm currently stuck.

@Mathemagician: You cannot prove it, because $f(| x | + k| x | ) > f(| x | ) + f( k | x | )$ for a strictly convex function.

Try doing it with an example in $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and a choosen function. Generalize then the process to a $X$ once you've visualized it.

I don't think you should restrict yourself to $y$ that is along $x$.
Let $S_\alpha$ be the sphere of radius $\alpha$ centred at the origin of $X$. Then $y\in S_\alpha$. Let $\beta := \|x\| > 0$. Then by triangle inequality we have
$$
|\alpha-\beta| \le \| x + y \| \le \alpha+\beta.
$$
Moreover, the map $S_\alpha \ni y \mapsto \|x+y\| \in [0,\infty)$ takes all values between $|\alpha-\beta|$ and $\alpha+\beta$ (because the two inequalities are saturated by $y=\pm \frac\alpha\beta x$, the norm is a continuous function with respect to the topology it induces: see here, and $S_\alpha$ is connected for $\dim X\ge2$). Then, since $f$ is continuous, the map $S_\alpha \ni y\mapsto f(\|x+y\|) \in \mathbb R$ takes all values between $f(|\alpha-\beta|)$ and $f(\alpha+\beta)$.
Now, by convexity, we have
$$
f(|\alpha-\beta|) \le f(\alpha) + f(\beta) \le f(\alpha+\beta).
$$
Here, the left inequality follows from monotonicity of $f$ (because $f'(0) \ge 0$ implies $f'(x) \ge 0$ for all $x\ge0$ since $f$ is convex), and the right inequality follows from convexity and $f(0)=0$. So the map $y\mapsto f(\|x+y\|)$ must attain the value $f(\alpha) + f(\beta)$ for some $y\in S_\alpha$. In other words, there is a $y \in S_\alpha$ such that
$$
f(\|x\|) + f(\|y\|) = f(\|x+y\|).
$$
